# Keep a wordpress sub-menu open for a few second

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have a wordpress menu like this one:

```
<div id="top_menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1"><a href="moo">moo</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2"><a href="foo">foo</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3"><a href="bar">bar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4"><a href="baz">baz</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

styled like this:

```
#top_menu ul li ul{
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    top:80px;
    width:auto;
    clear:both;
    border:0;
    border-top:none;
}
#top_menu ul li li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:none;
    width:auto;
}

#top_menu ul li ul a { 
    width:auto;
    line-height:26px;
    font-size:16px;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow: none;
}
#top_menu ul li:hover ul ul, #top_menu ul li:hover ul ul ul, #top_menu ul li.sfhover ul ul, #top_menu ul li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}
#top_menu ul li:hover ul, #top_menu ul li li:hover ul, #top_menu ul li li li:hover ul, #top_menu ul li.sfhover ul, #top_menu ul li li.sfhover ul, #top_menu ul li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
#top_menu ul li:hover, #top_menu ul li.sfhover { 
    position: static;
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JBXLr/1/

Now, if you go over "moo" sub-menu with foo and bar will be shown. My goal now is to keep that sub-menu open for let's say 2s after the mouse moves out of the "moo"-link-area. How can I do this?

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: What are your required compatibilities? For instance, css transitions could work, but aren't compatible across all browsers.

Comment: doesn't really matter as long as it works ;) I'l lgo with jQuery since it seems to be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use javascript (jQuery) to show sub-menu and apply [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$('#top_menu li').hover(function(){
    $('.sub-menu', this).show();
}, function(){
    $('.sub-menu', this).delay(2000).hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to work - "display:" is switching instantly from "block" to "none" ignoring the delay...

Comment: try to replace hide()  with fadeOut()

Answer (score 0):

Going to post this since you mentioned css. http://jsfiddle.net/JBXLr/3/ uses css3 transitions to achieve what you wanted.

Here is an alternate javascript solution that uses jquery and your current css.

```
​​​​$("li").mouseout(function(){
    var uls =$(this).children("ul");
    uls.css("left","auto");
setTimeout(function(){ uls.css("left",""); }, 2000);
});​​​
```